# How to read a generator expression

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python but not to programming languages. For that reason I am quite annoyed why I am having troubles deciphering the following line of code that I came across at work:

```
include_ = next((True for re_ in self.include_patterns if re_.match(name)), None)
```

I am already familiar with generators so I won'y need a thorough explanation on that. I don't understand what is the `next` doing and what is `True` actually doing. Other examples are welcomed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it just yields `True` if something is found, else it returns `None`, which is `next` default value when the generator reaches its end (which is IMHO not very good, it should return `False`).

`next` avoids to iterate fully. As soon as one of the pattern is found it stops.

But that's a bloated approach here (The `next(<gencomp>,None)` construct is still useful when you need the result from the generator, but not here)

Here, you can use `any` (and `or` if `any` returns `False` so you can yield `None` instead), since you just need `True` or ... something else.

```
include_ = any(re_.match(name) for re_ in self.include_patterns) or None
```

Comment: Yess I got it! Thank you +1. And you are right. This looks indeed a slightly confusing way to check whether a certain element occurs in a given iterable structure.